# Javascript Function Won't Execute, No matter what I do

Tags: javascript, execute, visible

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function appearbox(){
document.getElementById('hotelparoikia').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('desc1').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('desc2').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('typeofroom').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

As you can see, the above is the javascript code I have in my HTML file.

```
<form>
<table>
<tr><th>Επιλέξτε Περιοχή</th><th style="display:none;" id="desc1">Επιλέξτε ξενοδοχειακό συγκρότημα</th><th style="display:none;" id="desc2">Επιλέξτε τύπο δωματίου</th></tr>
<tr><td align="center">
<select id="hotelarea" onFocus="appearbox">
<option value="0" selected="selected" onFocus="appearbox" >ΠΑΡΟΙΚΙΑ</option>
<option value="1" onFocus="appearbox" >ΝΑΟΥΣΑ</option>
<option value="2" onFocus="appearbox" >ΧΡΥΣΗ ΑΚΤΗ</option>
<option value="3" onFocus="appearbox" >ΠΙΣΩ ΛΙΒΑΔΙ</option>
<option value="4" onFocus="appearbox" >ΑΛΙΚΗ</option>
</select>
</td>
<td align="center">
<select style="display:none;" id="hotelparoikia">
<option value="0" selected="selected">PAROS BAY HOTEL</option>
<option value="1">MARISA ROOMS</option>
<option value="2">AROKARIA BEACH</option>
<option value="3">REPPAS APARTMENTS</option>
<option value="4">VASSILIKI ROOMS</option>
</select>
</td>
<td align="center">
<select style="display:none;" id="typeofroom">
<option value="0" selected="selected">ΜΟΝΟΚΛΙΝΟ</option>
<option value="1">ΔΙΚΛΙΝΟ</option>
<option value="2">ΤΡΙΚΛΙΝΟ</option>
<option value="3">ΤΕΤΡΑΚΛΙΝΟ</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

This is another part of the code in my HTML file

As you can see, when the DropDownList is OnFocus, appearbox() should run and make some elements visible, but it won't run. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The _onFocus_ 's `appearbox` is most likely _undefined_ . You should separate your JavaScript from your HTML and attach it on load via `.addEventListener`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the ()

Alot of other suggestions here on using jQuery, separating the js logic, etc which are all probably good ideas conceptually. But as far as I can see the real problem with your html is right here ->

```
<select id="hotelarea" onFocus="appearbox">
```

it needs to be ->

```
<select id="hotelarea" onFocus="appearbox()">
```

because appearbox is just a function reference. The `()` is what says, essentially, "Run whatever function that reference points to."

Outside of that, if you make sure that your `<script>` tag is in the head (or anywhere else that will be loaded before the form) it should work fine.

If it still isn't working, open up the developer console in your browser (probably F12) and check the console to see if there is a error when you give the select box focus. I put your code almost exactly as is in a .html file (I put the script tag inside head and the form tag inside body, I also added the () to your onFocus listener. Otherwise it was a copy paste job) and it works, so as far as I can tell, the problem is one of:

- the missing ()
- script tag not loaded yet when onFocus listener created, you'll get an undefined error
- Some other stuff on your page is doing something funky like overwriting the definition of `appearbox` or something - pretty unlikely, but still, if you paste the whole page as is from the html file (or provide a jsfiddle link) then your answerers will be far better equipped to help.

Oh here's another thought on what it might be (pure guesses because I can't see the rest of your page). Does the form appear more than once on the page perhaps? Or, for any other reason, is there other elements on the page with those same ID's? if so, getElementById() will fail to return an element; ID's must be page-unique.

Comment: Your text about the "script must be before the onFocus listener is defined" is complete bollocks. Until the `onFocus` listener is *fired*, it won't bother checking its contents. Proof: `<button onClick="herpaderp()">` - the error will not appear in your console until you click the button.

Comment: Thanks for making a simple point in a snarky manner @NiettheDarkAbsol but as you might note, I gave that as a possibility because I cannot see the whole page's code, in case there are further problems after the brackets are added. For instance, if the select box gets focus when the page loads (either for being the first form element on the page or through other js not included in the question).

Answer (score 0):

```
onFocus="javascript:appearbox()"
```

But honestly, start using jQuery. Remove all onFocus from html and replace your js by:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hotelarea").focus(function() {
    $("#hotelparoikia").css("display", "block"); // or just .show()
    ...        
  });
});
```

Comment: Why jQuery? This is a simple task that can be completed with plain JavaScript. There's no complex DOM manipulation here or AJAX... This is about as rudimentary as JavaScript gets.

Comment: javascript doesn't work as-is. well, sometimes it might look as it's working, but don't get yourself fooled ;)

also, I strongly suggest to stop writing js code and start generating it from clojurescript or, at least, from coffeescript.

Comment: @iced JavaScript works as it is. It is the implementations in some browsers and how people write their code that determines how wide a user base you can have. Learning to write code properly is the real solution.

Comment: no it doesn't. [9, 10].sort() emits [10, 9] and it's only one of thousands examples I can come with (I'm aware why it's doing that and that it's documented, but it's still horrible).

Comment: iced, thank you very much for answering that fast. I tried your solution, but still, nothing seems to happen in the page :/

Comment: well, most likely, your js code is wrong. add aler(123) in start if it to check if it's called. and make sure to read http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ please.

Comment: I can agree that learning jQuery can be a really great tool and can save a lot of time and effort, I certainly don't think it is required here, you seem to be pretty dead-set that it is. I honestly think that's only going to add confusion. I know if I was told that I needed to learn a whole new framework just to modify css styles when I was this early into js I may well have just put js in the "no functionality" bin and gone back to *shudder* vbs.

Comment: can't agree here. it's actually "learn weird js ways for manipulating dom" (your approach) vs "learn more-less clean jQuery api (intro tutorial will be enough)". for bigger tasks you'll need jQuery anyway, so why learn things you'll NOT use. Heck, I wish I can forget what "getElementById()" is and why it sometimes works and sometimes not. Can't care less about NIH-infected browsers developers. also, I'm protecting myself - e.g. his small project will grow, will fail due to direct usage of js and he'll come here asking how to fix it ;)

Comment: NIH has nothing to do with it, he's not developing an xml parsing library or redefining arrays, nothing is being reinvented. Couldn't care less about developers who use a sledgehammer on a walnut. Also, I'm protecting myself. If everyone learns just jQuery and is shielded from plain js to the point of ignorance, what will they do when jQuery is behaving oddly and they need to troubleshoot it? They'll come straight here asking how to fix it, because they have no understanding of the backbone on which jQuery is built.

Comment: you are telling me that your average js developer can fix bug in jQ? have you looked at code? I'm not trying to start flame war here, really, but jQ isn't hammer, it's very lightweight library which supports virtually every browser capable running js, without any setup difficulties and easier to learn than general-js-nonsense-for-web. any other arguments against it?

Comment: since your response to any arguments against it seems to be "That's not really a problem" as supported by no evidence bar your word, I don't see any point. jQ isn't a hammer because you say it isn't. It's easier to learn because you say it is (that was not my experience of it btw). As I said at the start, jQuery is great, I use it daily. I just don't think that it invalidates the existence of other frameworks or framework-less js.

Comment: it doesn't of course. but other frameworks are either way less frequently used or are harder to learn (or heavy). I know my way around quite few of them (sadly, more experienced with prototype than with jQ). not-hammer/lightweight - it got only around 9K lines of js code (good half of each are comments). it's not highly specialized, on contrary - it's general purpose web js lib. and it's easy to learn - one of the best docs over here, with lots of useful examples for each function. I can bet that .show()/.hide() example will have exactly what needed in original question, just for copypaste.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/show/ - and indeed there is. first example isn't complete, others does just what he needs, with .click instead of .focus. real problem (which stopped him with pure js) could be solved with code from doc page. makes sense? if not, I'll stop here.

Comment: When you say that it is lightweight, in what spectrum is 9K lines of code lightweight for a problem that can be solved with 5? When you say "real problem (which stopped him with pure js)" which real problem is it? as far as I can tell no one knows the real problem yet, we're still guessing. I'm sure it can be solved with code from that page. I'm also pretty sure there would be a w3schools tut somewhere with working code for this. Does this make w3schools a good solution? my problem is not with you offering jQ as a solution, its that you position it as the ONLY solution.

Comment: got it. not I'm not proposing it as only solution - there are plenty other solutions which will work. I'm proposing it as best solution. anyway, pointless, stopping here ;)

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me just fine:

```
<select id="hotelarea" onFocus="javascript:appearbox();">
```

You don't need onFocus events in the option tags, just one inside the select tag is fine.

Comment: yes, my original code didn't have the onFocus events in the option tags, I added them as I was testing what could be wrong. The weird thing is, if I paste the code above, alone in a new file, then it works for me as well, but If I use it in the HTML I normally work on, then it doesn't work. Maybe I have something else wrong in the rest of the code...

Comment: Do you have a link to your entire page?

Comment: `javascript:` is unnecessary. This is a JS event, not a link.

Answer (score -2):

It's simple.

```
appearbox
// just a reference to the function

appearbox()
// call the function (with no arguments)
```

So:

```
onFocus="appearbox();"
```

Will work just fine.

Comment: Does this answer include any information that did not exist in the 3 other answers already on this page?